# How to create an infinity loop in this slider

Tags: javascript, loops, slider

Having difficulty adding an infinity loop (without using Jquery) to this slider so it will loop while continue going in the same direction.

window.addEventListener('load', function(){

```
// initialize variables

const slideCount = document.querySelectorAll('#slider-wrapper ul li').length;

const slideWidth = document.querySelector('#slider-wrapper').offsetWidth;

const totalWidth = slideCount * slideWidth + 'px';

const slider = document.querySelector('#slider-wrapper ul');

const next = document.querySelector('#next');

const previous = document.querySelector('#prev');

let leftPosition = 0;

let counter = 0;

// next button

slider.style.width = totalWidth;

    next.addEventListener('click', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        counter++;

        if (counter == slideCount) {

            counter = 0;
        
        }

        leftPosition = `-${counter * slideWidth}px`;            

        slider.style.left = leftPosition;

    });

    // previous button

    previous.addEventListener('click', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        counter--;

        if (counter < 0) {

            counter = slideCount-1;
        
        }

        leftPosition = `-${counter * slideWidth}px`;            

        slider.style.left = leftPosition;

    });
```

});

Trying to create an infinity loop without jquery, nothing has worked so far

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure you have read [ask], [mre] and [tour] to learn how this site works and how best to ask to get the best help. In this case, you should probably elaborate on what you want the slider to do exactly (loop through what? going in what direction?) as well as providing the HTML that this js is supposed to be working on. And it would be the best if you would format this in a code snippet (the [<>] button) for easy testing for the people who are looking at your question.